# Corrupted DataSet in .NET for failure testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dataset

Does anybody know of a way to create a `DataSet` such that when I call `GetXml()` on the `DataSet` I will get an exception?  I'm trying to write some failure testing for this scenario and am having a hard time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you write a subclass of DataSet such that its getXml() predictably throws an Exception?

Answer (score 1):

<s>This seems like testing for exceptions on `ToString()` calls. Some things don't need failure testing.</s>

You would get exceptions on creating/adding to a `DataSet`, so once you have a `DataSet` in memory that hasn't thrown an exception yet, it will always have a structure that allows `GetXml()` to work unexceptionally.

Update: looks like you can get it to throw an exception if you have two tables with a one-to-many relationship between them, set up the adapter to select multiple rows from the child table with the parent table info included in them, and then call `GetXml()`.

Comment: You can refer to this link: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/827334-dataset-getxml-returns-child-row-has-multiple-parents-exception
It seems it is possible to get an exception.

Comment: Interesting - I'll update my answer with a technique that should give you that exception.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation the [DataSet.GetXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml.aspx) method does not throw exceptions.

It may return an empty string or null (although the docs don't say so) <s>but it doesn't throw exceptions</s>.

You might avoid exceptions by *first* checking if the resulting DataSet contain any errors ([DataSet.HasErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.haserrors.aspx)) or even go so far as to check every table (DataTable.HasErrors) and every row (DataRow.HasErrors)?

Comment: Are you sure about that? http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/827334-dataset-getxml-returns-child-row-has-multiple-parents-exception

Answer (score 1):

Could you pass a null DataSet object to those functions which are calling GetXML? :-)

Comment: Yes, but that gets ArgumentNullException thrown, which is in a different catch. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Anything besides ArgumentNullException

Comment: Have you already tried :-

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/827334-dataset-getxml-returns-child-row-has-multiple-parents-exception

Answer (score 0):

You could simply throw the exception that a corrupted dataset would throw to emulate the problem

Comment: No, the method I'm testing calls dataSet.GetXML() and I need that to fail so it will hit the catch block (trying to get full code coverage).